# What is a unix command that will always return nothing no matter what parameters are given to it?

Tags: unix, shell

I want to put it at the top of a unix executable. right after the `#!`

I know it seems silly, but I would like suggestions.

Comment: To hide a file from a web server. Webserver will execute a .cgi and I want no result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most systems have a `/usr/bin/false`

```
NAME
     false -- Return false value.

SYNOPSIS
     false

DESCRIPTION
     The false utility always exits with a nonzero exit code.

SEE ALSO
     csh(1), sh(1), true(1)

STANDARDS
     The false utility conforms to IEEE Std 1003.2-1992 (``POSIX.2'').
```

Comment: It's usually `/bin/true` on modern systems. On which OS is it `/usr/bin/true`?

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka It's on Fedora 17 too. A funny story [here](http://trillian.mit.edu/~jc/humor/ATT_Copyright_true.html)  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for the "colon" built-in

> ```
>    : [arguments]
>          No  effect;  the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments
>          and performing any specified redirections.  A zero exit code  is
>          returned.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You could try `cat /dev/null`

["[T]he null device is a special file that discards all data written to it . . . and provides no data to any process that reads from it"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null)

Comment: I know, but there would be an argument. So it would turn into `cat /dev/null executable.sh` which would just reveal all my source code.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the argument? Are you passing the nothing to it? The pipe | character redirects output.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
 abort //does not return
```

or possibly

```
test true //returns 0
test false // returns 1
test       // returns 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your own in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

try empty backquotes

``

`echo $?`

gives 0 for this.